# Spark-submit with Stocator failing with Class com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem not found error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, cloud-object-storage, stocator

I am trying to run spark-submit wordcount Python on a Kubernetes cluster by pulling a text file stored in COS.

For the config, I followed the [Stocator README.md](https://github.com/CODAIT/stocator)

```
./bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://c111.us-south.containers.cloud.ibm.com:32206 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --packages com.ibm.stocator:stocator:1.1.3 \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.cos.myobjectstorage.access.key= --conf spark.hadoop.fs.cos.myobjectstorage.secret.key= --conf spark.hadoop.fs.stocator.scheme.list=cos --conf spark.hadoop.fs.cos.impl=com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem --conf spark.hadoop.fs.stocator.cos.impl=com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient --conf spark.hadoop.fs.stocator.cos.scheme=cos --conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy\
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=us.icr.io/mods15/spark-py:v1 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.cos.myobjectstorage.endpoint=http://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud --conf spark.hadoop.fs.cos.myobjectstorage.v2.signer.type=false --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py cos://vmac-code-engine-bucket.myobjectstorage/book.txt
```

I can see the driver and executors pods spinning up and after a couple of minutes the driver errors-out with the log below.

```
Driver stacktrace:
21/01/12 11:52:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at /opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py:40, took 7.839348 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py", line 40, in <module>
    output = counts.collect()
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 889, in collect
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 172.30.43.123, executor 4): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.<init>(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.text.TextFileFormat.$anonfun$readToUnsafeMem$1(TextFileFormat.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:153)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:295)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:607)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:383)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:218)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        ... 26 more
```

Any idea on how I can make this work? I want to pass the text file stored in COS to the wordcount Python example that comes with Spark download (examples folder)

I am using [Spark-3.0.1-hadoop2.7](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz) and for the container images, I followed the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part that is failing here is

`local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/wordcount.py cos://vmac-code-engine-bucket.myobjectstorage/book.txt`

For some reason, the wordcount.py is not able to pick the `book.txt` file in the COS.

Moving the cos file call inside the python file as mentioned in the [link here](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.1.1/developing-spark-applications/topics/spark-examples-of-accessing-s3-data-from-spark.html) solved the issue

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "count app")
sonnets = sc.textFile("cos://COS_BUCKET_NAME.COS_SERVICE_NAME/files")
counts = sonnets.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2: v1 + v2)
counts.saveAsTextFile("cos://COS_BUCKET_NAME.COS_SERVICE_NAME/files/wordcount-result")
```